# how get value onchange event from drop down event in select(chosen) jquery

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins, cakephp-2.3

i made drop down list with help of select jquery

```
echo $this->Form->input('Category', 
            array(
                'data-rel' =>'chosen',
                'style' => 'width:220px; margin-bottom:10px',
                'placeholder' => 'Select Category',
                'empty'=>'Select',
                'id'=>'ProductCategoryId',
                array('class'=>'required') 
                ));
```

now i'm trying to retrieve value onchange 
i tried following code to get value and text. (my basic purpose is to get value)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("#ProductCategoryId option:selected").text()); 
    alert($('#ProductCategoryId').val());
</script>
```

may be there are many answer of this question already on SO, but those did't resolve my problem.

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `});` at the end, and you do need to listen to the `change` event.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ProductCategoryId').on('change', function() {
        alert( $('option:selected', this).text() ); 
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the generated **HTML** for the `select` element.

Comment: thanks, now it is working, some code was wrong except this, so after removing that code now it is fine. thanks alot

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help. Feel free to accept this answer if your issue is permanently resolved.